# Strange color in today extension

Tags: ios, widget, ios10, today-extension

In iOS 10 I sometimes can notice strange colors of UI elements. You can see that some labels on screen are black. Sometimes UIImageViews are pink or red. I don't set the color of these views, but after 1 or 2 seconds after first loading the color changes and everything is ok.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was a bug in iOS because I noticed the same effect with other apps. Nothing can be done by iOS developer to remove this issue.